# Why web servers use a reverse proxy for SSL?

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy

Why web servers usually use a reverse proxy for SSL? I understand the concept of a reverse proxy and its usefulness to balance load among several servers, but not to implement SSL. Couldn't a web server simply create listening sockets in different ports for HTTP and HTTPS (i.e. HTTP with SSL) ?

Comment: This probably would suite more for ServerFault rather than here.

Comment: It's a lot simpler to have all the SSL certificates etc. in one place, and Tomcat for example doesn't give you nearly as much control over SSL as Apache HTTPD does, to name my own configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I frequently use Nginx as the reverse proxy.

Nginx serves as HTTPS frontend. It hosts the certificate and the private key, does HTTP->HTTPS redirect, adds necessary headers to the response and encapsulates the intranet.

The actual business logic is run by a Zoo of various servers in the intranet that serve over HTTP - nodejs, go, php. They run on different machines. Some of them are legacy and have no idea about TLS, some are a bit younger legacy and can TLS 1.1 only.

The reasons to use Nginx as the HTTPS frontend are:

1. I don't trust HTTPS implementations from third parties.
2. I don't want to mess with all the bells and whistles required by various implementations to attach a certificate.
3. I don't want to bother with legacy or third-party software that has outdated TLS version / ciphers configuration or miss HTTPS completely.
4. I like how Certbot automagically handles my certificates in Nginx.
5. I like neat feature of Nginx that neither of custom servers provide, such as HTTP-to-HTTPS redirection, load balancing, fast static pages and tons of others.

Comment: I can see the benefit of using a reverse proxy for SSL if you already have a proxy for caching/load balancing, but my original question is about a simpler scenario: why use a reverse proxy for SSL if you have just one web server (e.g. Apache) without caching/load balancing?